# Explicit generators of $\mathfrak{so}(6)$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm looking for a canonical way to write the matrix form of the $\mathfrak{so}(6)$ generators, either in printed or digital form or implemented in some programming language represented in arbitrary dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can program the basis and the Lie brackets of $\mathfrak{so}(6)$ yourself. Take the vector space of all $6\times 6$ skew-symmetric matrices, and chose a basis $X_1,\ldots ,X_{15}$. Then the Lie brackets are just given by the rule
$$
[X_i,X_j]=X_iX_j-X_jX_i.
$$

Comment: Of course there is a canonical way. Just as I said, take $X_1=E_{12}-E_{21}$ and so on. Here $E_{ij}$ is the matrix with entry $1$ at place $(i,j)$ and $0$ otherwise.